# ffmpeg subtitles background issue when multiple lines (using .srt format)

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, srt

While using `ffmpeg` to burn `.srt` subtitles to `mp4` files I'm having an issue with multiple text lines  - background is overlaying each other.

Command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i source_video_path.mp4 -vf "subtitles=srt_source.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=25,Fontname=Arial,Fontsize=10,Alignment=2'" video_destination.mp4
```

[image]

Question is - is it possible to overcome the overlay while still having a transparent background while using `.srt` format or I need to use `.ass` format as a fix?

Comment: Actually, `.ass` format doesn't support custom linespacing either (not to mention `libass` library is used for the both formats. Anyway, I found [this article](https://www.md-subs.com/line-spacing-in-ssa) if you decide to explorer `.ass` and  haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid multiple lines overlaying each other by using `BorderStyle=4` together with `BackColour=&H80000000` which gives a 50% opaque black color background.

Full command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i source_video_path.mp4 -vf "subtitles=srt_source.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=4,BackColour=&H80000000,Outline=0,Shadow=0,MarginV=25,Fontname=Arial,Fontsize=10,Alignment=2'" video_destination.mp4
```

[image]